# Is there a way to hide parameters in a smart contract?

Tags: encryption, private

Imagine we have a very simple contract which pays 1%, 1.2% or 3%(very special fee) on an anniversary basis.
But we don't want the different holders to know who are on what fee rate of others.
Obviously this is an oversimplification and seeing the amount paid to a user will allows to find the fee rate. But you get the idea.
Is there a way to do that? If there is an obvious ways pointers towards the right directions are fine

Answer (score 0):

Don't verify the smart contract on Etherscan or create a python/js script to do that

Comment: Paul-Constantin, thanks that's a good idea but I guess it would be a little more complex as just simple js / python would be transparent. I guess you would need to hash the values, store the private key in the script and finally compile the script?